# MVC: Using the routing attribute with a url that has an additional segment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I have a controller called **Search**.  A normal url would be the following:

- `localhost:44351/<ClientName>/Search/ByCity`

This would hit my **ByCity** action within my `SearchController`.

Now however, a url such as the following example, would also need to hit an action within the SearchController:

- `localhost:44351/<ClientName>/Search/Pharmacy/ByCity`

I need to somehow tell my **SearchController**, if the url contains "Pharmacy/ByCity", to go to the ByCity action.

I've tried using the routing attribute, but my app still hits my old Pharmacy action instead.

In my RouteConfig, I have this:

```cs
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();   
}
```

Then, in my `SearchController`, I have this:

```cs
public virtual ActionResult Pharmacy()
{
    //this is an existing action, which gets hit, even when I type in "Pharmacy/ByCity", which is not what I want to happen.
}

[Route("Pharmacy/ByCity")]
public virtual ActionResult ByCity()
{
    //this never gets hit
}
```

Any idea how to have a url containing "Pharmacy/ByCity" to hit my "ByCity" action, rather than "Pharmacy"?

Thanks

Comment: What is `ClientName` means? Is this just constant string or this is parameter with a variable value, that might take different values like `clientname1`, `clientname2`, etc.

Comment: @Jackdaw, "Clientname" is a variable value.  So it could have different values such as clientname1 & clientname2

Comment: Okay. I have updated routing in my answer below by using the conventional route set up, if this solution is acceptable for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to achieve with the conventional route by set up like below:

```cs
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Pharmacy",
    url: "{clientname}/{controller}/Pharmacy/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "search" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Search",
    url: "{clientname}/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "search", action = "Index" }
);          

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for what I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

Routes are accessed depending on their Order in the routing table.

For conventional routing (RouteConfig.cs), you could add your specific route before the default route.

1. Remove your `Route[]` attributes in the controller
2. Use the code below for RouteConfig

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
   routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

   // add your specific route, before the default route
   routes.MapRoute(
      name: "SearchByCity", // random name
      url: "Search/Pharmacy/ByCity",
      defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "ByCity" }
   );
   
   // this is the default route
   routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );
}
```

---

If you want to use Attribute Route, follow steps below.

1. Remove the default route in RouteConfig.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
   routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
   routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
}
```

2. Then use the controller below, we used `RoutePrefix` for the controller, and `Route` for the actions.

```
[RoutePrefix("Search")]
public class SearchController : Controller
{
   [Route("Pharmacy")]
   public virtual ActionResult Pharmacy()
   {
      return View("index");
   }

   [Route("Pharmacy/ByCity")]
   public virtual ActionResult ByCity()
   {
      return View("index");
   }
}
```